# Access SSRS web portal remotely

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have configured SSRS on reporting server and everything working but user can access Web portal from their machine. The users already have access to reporting server but they can't access the site.

Is it possible to host Web portal on IIS?

Your feedback is highly appreciated